# Maintain Unique Array In Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Below code represent that 101 has initiated chat with 102.

```
db.chat.insert(
   {
     "mydate" : ISODate(),
     "chatusers" : [101,102]
   }
)
```

To make sure this entry is unique and there should be no duplicate like
[101,102] or [102,101] is tried to add unique index in chatusers but this does not work on pairs as it dont allow to use either of 101 or 102.

Question:
One way is to make sure at application end or should i change my collection schema?
What is the better approach and please suggest schema for the same.

Note:
select Queries will be based on both sender and receiver.

Comment: Well [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) is actually right up the top the search results for your question title. It's amazing what search engines can do.

Comment: @NeilLunn: `$addToSet` maintains unique elements within an array. The question, I understand, is how to ensure uniqueness of the arrays within the collection.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Nope I disagree. The question is asking to ensure that `[101,102]` is the same as `[102,101]`. Which is called a "set" the last I checked.

Comment: @NeilLunn i also got the result but do you think its better approach rather than its should be handled in schema. what do you say ?

Comment: @NeilLunn: I agree on definition of set. I'm just not sure _that_ is what's being asked :)

Comment: @NeilLunn: as far as I can see, the question is "how to prevent creation of another chat room with all the same users".

Comment: @user746709 There are hundreds of questions here that ask the *"how do I make an index for this.."* variant of exactly the same thing you are asking. The **only** answer is "You do not". Instead you use the operator that ensures the "set" . Or you check for the presence of the member when "adding" Ie. With `$ne`. But that is only needed with objects in the array. Simple values are a "set". How is everyone misreading this is what beats me.

Comment: The array size contains just 2 elements sender and receiver. and the combination should be unqiue. Based on google i am not sure if aray is right choice ?

Comment: Perhaps you should phrase your question better. All I see here is people getting carried away with misunderstanding it. maybe "unique" should be on "participantOne" and "participantTwo" as a combination if you are looking to ensure only one document ever has that combination of values. But your question should be clearer if "document" is the intent.

Answer (score 1):

> The array size contains just 2 elements sender and receiver. and the combination should be unique. Based on google i am not sure if array is right choice ?

Yes, array is not the right choice because 1) mongodb gives them special treatment and 2) semantically, two arrays with different order of elements are **different** arrays.

So, assuming that your array works well enough to satisfy your queries and whatnot, here's how you can ensure uniqueness of the combinations:

Make a synthethic derived field of properly indexable type. String, for example. So, for `"chatusers" : [102,101]`, you take the chat users, **sort** them and concatenate, producing something like this:

```
 "chatusers_sig": "101,102"
```

Now you can build unique index on this field. Just don't forget to update it when chat users array changes (if it does).

Comment: "102,101" is a different value the last time I checked. If it's "document" uniqueness, then the values need to be in "separate" fields, with a compound unique index.

Comment: @NeilLunn: nah, it's collection-wide uniqueness. Of sets.

Comment: Try it and see. And try not to be glib. I'm giving you some sound advice that this does not maintain uniqueness

Comment: @sergio  i feel there should be 2 column and unique on column is better choice as this as i can see "chatusers" and "chatusers_sig" is duplicate information

Comment: @NeilLunn: I fail to see how this does not maintain uniqueness. Assuming two chat rooms with users [101, 102] and [102, 101], their sig fields will _both_ be "101,102" (the sorting). And the second one will fail to insert.

Comment: what about duplicate data ??

Comment: @user746709: honestly, if you care much about not duplicating data, mongodb is not the right database.

Comment: @user746709: if your rooms always have only two users, you can store them in separate fields (applying some sorting too, so that lowest id always goes to field 1, for example). Then you can build a compound unique index over two simple fields, as Neil suggested. But this is not an option when your rooms can have variable number of participants. It all depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by Sergio seems correct.

```
db.chat.insert(
   {
     "mydate" : ISODate(),
     "chatusers" : [101,102],
     "chat_sig" : "101_102"
   }
)
```

The solution suggested by Neil has a basic flaw.

```
db.chat.insert(
   {
     "mydate" : ISODate(),
     "sender"  : 101,
     "receiver": 102,
   }
)
```

Adding compound unique index on sender and receiver will guarantee that sender-receiver = 101-102  do not repeat but 102-101 can still exist and hence basic requirement does not meet

Comment: How is this answer upvoted/accepted, but mine is not? :puzzled:

Comment: @SergioTulentsev agreed, your answer should be an acceptable answer. I can just upvote your answer.